# Three yods in a Get

Tags: talmud-gemara, divorce, maseches-gitin

https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.85b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en. The gemara says that there are two words in a *get* (Jewish divorce document) that should be written with *three* consecutive yods: דיתיהו**ייי**ן דיתיצב**ייי**ן, to avoid a misunderstanding by reading them wrong. See Rashi and Tosefos there for some information. I wonder if someone could explain the pronunciation of both the correct and incorrect possibilities, and especially enough Aramaic grammar so that I can understand what the choices are.
Thanks!

Comment: Are the pronunciations indicated in your Sefaria link not sufficient?

Comment: Well, I need an explanation for that as well. I asked what they mean, but I guess also, How do the three yods help you get that and not something else?

Comment: I do note that there are no triple yods anywhere in Tanach, and nowhere else in the Talmud. This does not seem to be a normal spelling for anything. What's going on?

Comment: See the Rambam on this who discusses that one may mistakenly think one is referring to 2 women if two yuds are placed ,so 3 yuds are added to note that we are talking about about 1 woman only. It seems like the correct way to read it is with a chirik ,and not with a tzeirei .

Comment: Well, I think Rashi says that too, about the two women.